# Best way to emulate inheritance of static classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-classes

**Background**: I have a standard code list of string `const`s (in static classes) in a library that may be shared across several projects, run both internally and externally. (This library has a primary function that is not solely for storing these strings). These codes are standardized and should not change, and a database to store these values is not a useful solution.

One of these lists is **colors**. A vehicle, for example, may use a basic list of colors that includes things like red, black, blue, grey, etc. A person's hair color can also be any of those standard colors, but has additional options - such as blonde - that do not apply to things that are not hair.

When using this library, I would want to use `StandardCodes.Colors.Black` for a vehicle and `StandardCodes.Person.HairColors.Black` for a hair color. Because the string for black is always `"BLK - Black"`, I don't want to duplicate that multiple times for each class that uses it. And when looking for the hair color black, I would expect to start with `StandardCodes.Person.HairColors.` and have `Black` come up as an option. If it did not, I (or another person) would have to know to look in `StandardCodes.Colors` for it, which is not ideal.

This would seem to be a simple case for the use of inheritance - `HairColors`, and similar lists like `EyeColors` would derive from `Colors`.

Example of this structure:

```
public static class StandardCodes
{
    public static class Colors
    {
        public const string Black = "BLK - Black";
        public const string Gray  = "GRY - Gray";
        public const string White = "WHI - White";
    }

    public static class Person
    {
        public static class HairColors : Colors
        {
            public const string Blonde = "BLN - Blond or Strawberry";
            public const string Sandy  = "SDY - Sandy";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, of course, is that static classes cannot derive from other classes.

Is it best to make these classes not static and hide the constructors? Or is there another, better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: RE: "I don't want to duplicate that multiple times for each class that uses it". Why? If it's a small list and it never changes this is maybe well be a good case for "duplication over inheritance". It won't be any less efficient as strings are interned. Black hair is not the same as black paint and in the future when someone decides that cars should be allowed to be "matte black" or "metallic black" you won't have to worry about your hair colors.

Comment: True, I did forget about strings being interned. Though if "matte black"/"metallic black" colors were added, ideally they would be in a new `VehicleColors` class.

Comment: And then you add another class 'Toys' and you want to use "metallic black" too there and then it all breaks down, as it always does when you use inheritance. In my experience, inheritance should be avoided unless it's physically impossible to have anything other than a tree structure, ever. I wish every lecture on OOP came with a warning not a recommendation for inheritance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `static` class at the route of your hierarchy and then create an instance for the properties.  Something like this:

```
public static class StandardCodes
{
    public static Colors Colors = new Colors();
    public static class Person
    {
        public static HairColors HairColors = new HairColors();
    }
}
public class Colors
{
    public readonly string Black = "BLK - Black";
    public readonly string Gray  = "GRY - Gray";
    public readonly string White = "WHI - White";
}

public class HairColors : Colors
{
    public readonly string Blonde = "BLN - Blond or Strawberry";
    public readonly string Sandy  = "SDY - Sandy";
}
```

Comment: Does this prevent calling the constructor of `Colors` or `HairColors` like `new StandardCodes.HairColors()`?

Comment: The constructor should be called when the static classes are loaded into memory, when the app start.  You could check this with a debugger.

Comment: Now that I've had a chance to test: 
**--** The static field `StandardCodes.Colors` gives a compile-time error "**The type '`StandardCodes`' already contains a definition for '`Colors`'.**"
**--** Both of these `var b = new StandardCodes.Colors();` `var c = new StandardCodes.HairColors();` are valid but meaningless lines of code. 
**--** `StandardCodes.Person.HairColors.`... references the instance, not the class, which only has the `.Equals()`/`.ToString()`/etc methods, and none of the `const` strings.

Comment: You can resolve the 'type already exists' error by moving the Colors class outside of the scope of StandardColors (put it below the final `}`).